# PHP mail function issue with hotmail?

Tags: macos, hotmail, php

I have created a script on mac OS X and it successfully sent an email to my gmail account but when i tried to use it to my hotmail account it didn't work is it because hotmail uses a spam filter or what?

I used the same code with gmail and it worked but it didn't work with hotmail.

Anybody knows what might have gone wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for an SMTP server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to avoid a system generated e-mail going into spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800898/php-how-to-avoid-a-system-generated-e-mail-going-into-spam) and *so* many others... If it's not going to the spam folder, then this isn't really a programming question we can help you with.

Comment: I am using sendmail program came with mac and trying to send the email from my gmail account to my hotmail account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using it directly from your own computer? Then yes, you may be reported as spam (sometimes, mails doesn't even show up in the spam box)
Try to play with the headers (for example, "from" should be the same domain as your server), and avoid "spammy" words in content of the mail.

Comment: What i have noticed is that it sometimes doesn't work like right now it doesn't even work with gmail or anything so confusing

Comment: thanks a lot i have took a look at the mail.log and found out that the spam filter that gmail and also the hotmail replayed that i am not authorized to send an email

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the "sendmail" program that comes on OS X is actually Postfix.

You need to set up Postfix to send e-mail through GMail's servers, not directly.

One guide I found is [here](http://www.riverturn.com/blog/?p=239).  There are certainly many others.  You end up having to turn on SSL through some configuration, as I recall.